# Jenkins pipeline returns "Bad Subtitution" for shell command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm attempting to run the following command in a shell block in my Jenkins pipeline:

```
jq '.Resources[].TargetService.Properties.TaskDefinition = "'"arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:${ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:task-definition/${TASK_NAME}:${NEW_REVISION}"'"'
```

This command works perfectly fine when I run it directly on the Jenkins node in shell.

When I insert it into the Pipeline like this:

```
stage('process json') {
    steps {
        dir('mydir') {
            sh """
                NEW_REVISION=\$(cat revision.txt)
                jq '.Resources[].TargetService.Properties.TaskDefinition = "'"arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:\${env.AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:task-definition/\${env.TASK_NAME}:\${NEW_REVISION}"'"'
            """
        }
    }
}
```

I get a `Bad substitution` error without any more information. As far as I know, I'm escaping variables and quotation correctly. I can bypass the error if I remove the double quotes like this:

```
jq '.Resources[].TargetService.Properties.TaskDefinition = "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:${ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:task-definition/${TASK_NAME}:${NEW_REVISION}"'
```

But that ends up processing the variables literally.

Notes: I'm aware of the security issue by not passing `jq --arg` and prepared to modify my command after I can get the simpler format working. revision.txt contains a numeric value. The `env.*` variables are declared earlier as part of the pipeline environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`env` is a Jenkins Object and you seem to be escaping `env.*` variables as well. If you have already exported these variables as Environment variables they should be available to you in the shell environment. So simply drop the `env` part from the variables or remove the escape characters from such variables and let Jenkins interpolate them.

```
stage('process json') {
    steps {
        dir('mydir') {
            sh """
                NEW_REVISION=\$(cat revision.txt)
                jq '.Resources[].TargetService.Properties.TaskDefinition = "'"arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:\${AWS_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}:task-definition/\${TASK_NAME}:\${NEW_REVISION}"'"'
            """
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely fixed the issue. Under what circumstance do the Environment variables need to be called with the env prefix, then?

Comment: @MikeD You can use `env.VARIABLE` if you want to access Environment variables from your Groovy code. Or if you want to set an environment variable from the Groovy code.